# Define types for generic static member in a 3rd party module

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a 3rd party module that looks something like this:

```js
export class Container{
  
  static async action() { 
     return {...}
  }
  
  constructor(params = {}) {
   // ...
  }
  
  async doSomething(params = {}) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I want to try and describe this in `d.ts`

```js
declare module 'container' {
   interface ContainerImpl<T>{
      doSomething(params: Partial<T>): Promise<T>
   }
   
   export const Container: {
      new <T>(params: T): ContainerImpl<T>;
      action<T>(): Promise<T>
   }
}
```

This is **ALMOST** what I want. I am trying to see if there is a way to basically make that export generic. So the compiler understands that the static side does not need to explicitly specify `T` for `action(): Promise<T>`. What am I after is a kind of Generic Container `Constructible<T>` whose `new` vends `ContainerImpl<T>`:

```js
import { Container } from 'container';

type MyObject = {
   value: string
}

class MyContainer extends Container<MyObject>{}

// compiler assumes return is Promise<MyObject>
// since we are a Conatiner<MyObject>
// example only, ignore that this is a top level await.
await MyContainer.action() 

// expect MyObject type in constructor and assumes a 
// `ContainerImpl<MyObject>` is returned from the constructor.

const impl = new MyContainer({value: 'test'});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you made a typo in `import {Conatiner} from 'container';`

It shoulb be Container.

Second, you can't use top level await. You should wrap it into `async` function.

```js
import { Container } from 'container';

type MyObject = {
    value: string
}

class MyContainer extends Container<MyObject>{ }


const foo = async () => {
    await MyContainer.action()

}

const impl = new MyContainer({ value: 'test' });

impl.doSomething // ContainerImpl<MyObject>.doSomething(params: Partial<MyObject>): Promise < MyObject >

type Impl = typeof impl

type Test = ReturnType<Impl['doSomething']> // Promise<MyObject>
```

You was very close and your types works as expected

Comment: Thanks for the typo correction, and I should have been more clear in the question re: that top level `await` that was not meant to be taken literally, I have updated the comment around that as well. The crux of the problem remains though. `MyContainer.action` a `static` function needs to be able to know it returns `MyObject`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can specify narrower types for static methods in subclasses, even if you don't replace the implementation. You will need to adjust the signature for `action()` though:

```
declare module "container" {
  interface ContainerImpl<T> {
    doSomething(params: Partial<T>): Promise<T>;
  }

  export const Container: {
    new <T>(params: T): ContainerImpl<T>;
    action(): Promise<unknown>;
  };
}
```

```
class MyContainer extends Container<MyObject> {
  static action: () => Promise<MyObject>;
}
```

Comment: This was a nice direction to take it. I was trying to find some other patterns that were like this and ORMs came to mind: `Foo.get()`, `Foo.all()` where `get` and `all` are static and would be expected to return a type `Foo`. That lead me to `sequelize`. They have this requirement as well it seems: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/main/types/lib/model.d.ts#L1624-L1627.